# Writing a java algorithm equivalent to the sql select query which uses inner join and group by clause

Tags: java, algorithm

Need to write the java code (algorithm) equivalent to the below sql query -

```
select u.browsers, a.app_name, count(*) 
as no_of_apps from users u inner join apps a 
where u.user_id = a.user_id group by u.browsers, a.app_name order by no_of_apps limit 0,2.
```

There are two different .tsv files (user.tsv and app.tsv) and the format of data they contains is -

+1.users.tsv

```
user_id   browsers

1         Mozilla
2         Mozilla
3         Chrome
```

+2. apps.tsv

```
app_id    user_id     app_name

1          1           HelloWorld
2          3           Sonar
3          1           Sonar
4          2           HelloWorld
5          1           HelloWorld
```

Here user_id is acting like a Foreign key in apps.tsv file. What I really need is the algorithm in java to get data from the two files something like this -

```
browsers     app_name      no_of_apps

Mozilla     HelloWorld      3
Mozilla     Sonar           1  
Chrome      Sonar           1
```

Code I wrote for this is -

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        //cloumn places
        int state_col = 2;
        int user_col = 0;
        int jobid_col = 2;
        List<String> userLines = null;
        List<String> appLines = null;
        String[][] userResultArray = null;
        String[][] appResultArray = null;

        Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String, String> appMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> userJobMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        List<Integer> app = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            userLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/home/indg/java-spring/spring/idea_workspace/Task1/tabFiles/users.tsv"));
            appLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/home/indg/java-spring/spring/idea_workspace/Task1/tabFiles/apps.tsv"));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



        if(userLines != null) {
            userResultArray = new String[userLines.size()][];

            for(int i =0; i<userLines.size()-1; i++){
                userResultArray[i] = userLines.get(i).split("\t"); //tab-separated
                if(userResultArray[i][state_col] != "" && userResultArray[i][state_col] != null) {
                    userMap.put(userResultArray[i][user_col],userResultArray[i][state_col]);
               }

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in reading line");
        }

        if(appLines != null) {
            appResultArray = new String[appLines.size()][];

            for(int i =0; i<appLines.size()-1; i++){
                appResultArray[i] = appLines.get(i).split("\t"); //tab-separated
                if(appResultArray[i][jobid_col] != "" && appResultArray[i][jobid_col] != null) {
                    appMap.put(appResultArray[i][user_col], appResultArray[i][jobid_col]);
                }

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in reading line");
        }

        for(String userKey: userMap.keySet()) {
            //System.out.println(userEntry.getKey() + "**");
            String jobId = appMap.get(userKey);
            if(jobId != null && userMap.get(userKey) != null && userMap.get(userKey) != "" ) {

                userJobMap.put(userMap.get(userKey), jobId);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(userJobMap + " --");

    }   
}
```

I want to apply order by and limit in the query too for example - order by no_of_apps limit 0,2 how to do that in the code

Comment: Show us the code you have tried. Does it work? If not, do you get any errors?

Comment: Please find the code at this link - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8Nnd496GlTJRzhPLVRCeWh4N0k/edit?pli=1   

Got stuck . Don't even know that whether I am on the right track or not

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26411312/edit) and include the relevant parts of your code. We will not read your code outside of StackOverflow.

Comment: You write: "Got stuck after userJobMap". That is too broad. Please describe what your code shall do, what it acutally does, and what errors you get.

Comment: No errors actually what i mean is - userJobMap gives key value pair of {browser=app, browser1=app1}. now i am not getting how to get count here and apply group by clause by browser first and by app later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> userLines = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1\tMozilla", "2\tMozilla", "3\tChrome" });
        List<String> appLines = Arrays
                .asList(new String[] { "1\t1\tHelloWorld", "2\t3\tSonar", "3\t1\tSonar", "4\t2\tHelloWorld", "5\t1\tHelloWorld" });

        Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

        if (userLines != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < userLines.size(); i++) {
                String[] userResultArray = userLines.get(i).split("\t"); // tab-separated
                userMap.put(userResultArray[0], userResultArray[1]);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in reading line");
        }

        if (appLines != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < appLines.size(); i++) {
                String[] appResultArray = appLines.get(i).split("\t"); // tab-separated
                if (userMap.containsKey(appResultArray[1])) {
                    String userName = userMap.get(appResultArray[1]);
                    if (resultMap.containsKey(userName)) {
                        Map<String, Integer> map = resultMap.get(userName);
                        Integer n = map.get(appResultArray[2]) == null ? 0 : map.get(appResultArray[2]);
                        map.put(appResultArray[2], ++n);
                    } else {
                        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        map.put(appResultArray[2], 1);
                        resultMap.put(userName, map);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in reading line");
        }

        // sort
        Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        for (String userName : resultMap.keySet()) {
            for (String app : resultMap.get(userName).keySet()) {
                Integer n = resultMap.get(userName).get(app);
                List<String> list = sortedMap.get(n) == null ? new ArrayList<String>() : sortedMap.get(n);
                list.add(userName + "\t" + app);
                sortedMap.put(n, list);
            }
        }

        int limit = 0;

        outer:
        for (Integer n : sortedMap.keySet()) {
            for (String s : sortedMap.get(n)) {
                System.out.print(s);
                System.out.println("\t" + n);
                if (++limit == 2) break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for curosity if I want to apply order by and limit in the query too for example - order by no_of_apps limit 0,2 how to do that in the code.

Comment: @Aditya Khajuria Regarding your question: you may use 3-dimensional List instead of Map and sort it. An you can limit the output using a simple counter

Comment: @Aditya Khajuria I updated the code. It's not very thought-out but should work

Comment: +1 for your code and help and this code is great. Thanks